# grails2.5.0 Unable to download plugin dependencies

Tags: java, docker, grails, grails-2.0

There are some problems when containerizing a Grails project. I have never contacted Grails before. This problem has troubled me for a long time. I hope you can help me solve it

---

grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5"
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.7
grails.project.source.level = 1.7
grails.server.port.http = 8080
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    inherits("global") {}
    log "warn"
    checksums true
    legacyResolve false
    repositories {
        inherits true
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenRepo "our maven Repo"
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile group: 'com.ctrip.framework.apollo', name: 'apollo-client', version: '0.11.0-SNAPSHOT'
        compile group: 'com.alibaba', name: 'dubbo', version: '2.6.0'
        compile('org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:3.4.9') {
            excludes 'slf4j-log4j12'
        }

        compile group: 'com.101tec', name: 'zkclient', version: '0.2'
        compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '18.0'
    }

    plugins {
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55.3"
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.10"
        runtime ":shiro:1.2.1"
    }
}
```

---

When using the docker image proactivehk/grails:2.5.0 [(image link)](https://hub.docker.com/layers/proactivehk/grails/2.5.0/images/sha256-70a7354c5320cc5770bb98d0cdef3cb082dee7232497f79a9e93c739b89896ea?context=explore) to package the project, the following error occurred

> | Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:zip:4.3.10, org.grails.plugins:shiro:zip:1.2.1: Could not transfer artifact org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:zip:4.3.10 from/to grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

DockerFile：

```
FROM proactivehk/grails:2.5.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
CMD grails prod war
```

> I also tried using the command grails -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 prod war

---

I can run or package this project normally in the local IDE (windows / IntelliJ IDEA), but I don't know why it can't work normally in the container.

Answer (score -1):

Well I would say it's because Grails has removed all community plugins for 2.0 AND bintray is now offline as well... but if I say something like that they will delete this comment. ;)

Comment: But the strange thing is that I can run normally locally, I also found the required plug-in [here] (https://repo.grails.org/artifactory/plugins/org/grails/plugins/), but I don’t know how to deal with this problem

Comment: I don't think the problem described in question is affected by the absence of bintray.  The system is attempting to resolve the dependencies from our Artifactory and a handshake failure is happening.

Comment: "Well I would say it's because Grails has removed all community plugins for 2.0" - We didn't remove community plugins for 2.0.  They are still out there and we resolve them routinely.

Comment: You removed them from Grails site Jeff. You no longer list them. Hence, you removed them. Grails maintained a list of all Grails plugins and a repository for them all. They no longer do this for community plugins... only for OCI employees.